# Dataset<Row> and JavaRDD<Row>: how to eliminate the header

Tags: java, apache-spark

I would like to apply a  regression to my data. One of the workflow is the prepare my data as a JavaRDD  starting from a Dataset with its header.  So, what I did was the following:

== Step 1: transform the Dataset  into JavaRDD

```
    JavaRDD<Row> dataPointsWithHeader =modelDS.toJavaRDD();
```

== Step 2: take the first row (I was thinking that it was the header)

```
Row header= dataPointsWithHeader.first();
```

== Step 3: eliminate the row header by

```
JavaRDD<Row> dataPointsWithoutHeader = dataPointsWithHeader.filter((Row row) -> {
            return !row.equals(header);
        });
```

The issue with the above approach are:

a) the result of the Step 2 is not the header row;

b) the application of the Step 3 is very inefficient in case there is a way to access to the header.

My question is:

Is there an efficient way to access to the header and eliminate it ?

Many Thanks in advance for your help and suggestion.

Regards,
Carlo

Comment: It does not provide a practical solution though.

Answer (score 0):

This should be super simple.

if you need to header for the given Data-set, when you can use in build functions.

```
String[] header = modelDS.columns();
```

you can directly operate all your operation by operating in top of your `modelDS` variable itself.